# Pom File show Failure to transfer org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0

Tags: spring, apache-poi, pom.xml

While adding dependency of poi-ooxml my pom file showing me error of

Failure to transfer org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Is your internet connection broken? What happens if you force it?

Comment: I forcefully delete my local .m2 repo for apache poi, yet it didn't work

Comment: Got the answer 

First remove the dependency for local .m2 repo and than follow the steps

Go to project->Maven->update project->Tick the checkbox ForceUpdate and snapshot release

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer First remove the dependency for local .m2 repo and than follow the steps Go to project->Maven->update project->Tick the checkbox ForceUpdate and snapshot release

Comment: This solution is also working without removing dependency from local .m2.